# TRIAL4: Display only those numbers in your array list that are greater than your third input

Tags: c#

Display only those numbers in your array list that are greater than your third input.

Sample
Output:
Ilan: 5       Inputs: 15 6 11 2 12
The numbers greater than 11  is/are: 15 12

Sample Output: Ilan: 7
Inputs: 12   2  6   8   1  3  9
The numbers greater than 6 is/are: 8    9     12

Comment: It's advisable to show what you have tried and researched before asking the question. I think it is also a lttle bit off-topic, looks like a "homework question" (No, I don't want to resurrect the discussion on the homework tag :-)  but this looks like a "not a real question")

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Where` method in `System.Linq` namespace:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

var newNumbers = numbers.Where(x => x > 5);
```

`newNumbers` variable contain numbers are grater than 5.